# WP Gather Information from a button?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create a new uri, and I'm trying to use some information from several buttons.

On the XAML i have for example 3 buttons, all the buttons have the same `Click="button_clicked"`
when that button is clicked i want a piece of information from the button that was clicked i.e. its Content, and use it in a new uri.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    newurl.findurl = ("http://website.com/" + Content + ".zip");
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WebPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));         
}
```

If I use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline(Content);` all I get is this `System.Windows.Controls.Grid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an arbitrary parameter to most UI Objects by using the `.Tag property`.  For example

Click on the button and check out the Property

Change the Tag to anything you like.  If you want to pass an object it can be done as well

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Tag = your_object;
```

Now in your Button_Click event

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // get the button
    Button b = sender as Button;
    object your_object = b.Tag;

}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you i ended up using var obj = sender as Button; string content = obj.Tag.ToString();  newurl.findurl = content;